# Node.js delete query for "mongodb"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have been trying to understand why this delete query doesn't work for days, and I just can't see the problem. 
I've tried many different delete queries like deleteOne, findOneAndDelete, deleteMany but none of them worked. 
I use the "mongodb" client for node.js

```
mongo.connect(serverAddress, (err, db) => {
//(db connection is ok, server can find and create documents)

    var doc = db.collection('myCollection'),
    docToDelete = "575807172154b7a019ebf6db"; 
    //I can see the same document id on my database

    doc.deleteOne({"_id":docToDelete}, (err, results) => { 
        console.log(`Request success : ${results.result.ok}, documents deleted : ${results.result.n}`);
        //Request success : 1, documents deleted : 0, the document is still on my database
    });
}
//the doc var is the same I use to add/find documents (and it works).
```

When I use the same query in softwares like MongoClient, it works. 
I have tried many solutions posted on this site and sorry if the error is too obvious but I'm totaly lost.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `_id` in the database is of type `ObjectId`, but in your query it's a `String`. You have to be strict about that, otherwise the query won't match the document.

Try this:

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
...
doc.deleteOne({ _id : mongodb.ObjectId(docToDelete) }, (err, results) => {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Many thanks ! I remember having seen this ObjectId method somewhere in mongo documentation but I did not make the connection ...